# Filtering and projecting an association using NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Suppose you have an entity similar to this:

```
public class Mailinglist
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subscriber> Subscribers { get; set; }
}
```

The NHibernate mapping for the entity is as you would expect: `Id` is the identifier and `Subscribers` is mapped with `<set>` and `<many-to-many>` referincing a `Subscriber` entity.

Now, I am in a situation where I have an instance of `Mailinglist` and need to obtain a list of the first 100 subscribers matching some filter on `Subscriber` properties. Due to performance constraints, and the amount of data in the database, `myMailinglist.Subscribers.Where().Take()` is not an option. Hence, I am trying to put together a query for NHibernate which will fetch just the 100 `Subscriber` instances from the database.

My initial attempt (without any filtering) goes like this:

```
var subscribers = session
    .QueryOver<Mailinglist>()
    .Where(m => m.Id == myMailinglistId)
    .JoinQueryOver(m => m.Subscribers)
    .Take(100)
    .List();
```

This is obviously not right, as the list I get back contains 100 references to the `Mailinglist` which I already new about. The generated SQL looks pretty good though, leaving me to think that I just need to explicitly add a projection/transformation.

I've been trying to find some relevant documentation to help me along, but cannot seem to find anything addressing this sort of querying. Can somebody hint me along?

Comment: Subscribers doesnt had a FK to MailingList? Why can't you just do a QueryOver<Subscribers>.Where(s => s.MailingListId == myMailinglistId and ...).Take(100).List(); ?

Comment: does a subscriber have a backreference to a mailinglist?

Comment: The relation between `Subscriber` and `Mailinglist` is many-to-many. Currently, `Subscriber` does not have any back reference, but I don't see any problem in adding a `Mailinglists` collection property on it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Mailinglist>()
    .Where(m => m.Id == myMailinglistId)
    .JoinQueryOver(m => m.Subscribers, () => subscriber)
    .Select(m => subscriber.Id);

var subscribers = session.QueryOver<Subscriber>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(s => s.Id).In(subquery)
    .Take(100)
    .List();
```

Answer (score 0):

Would HQL not be easier to read?

Have not tested but something in the lines of:

```
Query query = 
 session.createQuery("from Mailinglist m where m.subscriber = :code ")
.SetMaxResults(100)
.setParameter("code", "%john%");
List list = query.list();
```

The setMaxResults should translate to T-SQL "select top 100..."